# How to format the html in a Wolox react chat using SSE

Tags: reactjs

I want to implement a chat that uses SSE and receives words one at a time like a gpt chat

The problem is that I also receive data in html format, or new lines, etc.
How could I format the words that come so that the chat format looks nice? Now all the words are placed next to each other
My code

```
const answerElement = document.createElement('div');
answerElement.className = 'rcw-message';
answerElement.innerHTML = `
  <div class="rcw-response" style="white-space: initial">
    <div class="rcw-message-text">
      <p id="${messageId}"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
`;
```

I m using this chat

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-chat-widget
```

Comment: See note on security re: `innerHTML` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML#security_considerations